# Sort array of arrays by while using options_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting

I have array like following:

```
[[value1, value2],[value1, value2], [value1, value2]]
```

How do i sort this array by `value1` without manually iterating over array. Are there any built in ways to do this? I want simply sort by Alphabet(In this array i have user_name as value1 and user_id as value2, and using `options_for_select` rails method to pass collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
ary.sort_by {|ary| ary.first }
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this? Just use `Array#sort`

```
a = [["def",1],["abc", 2],["de", 5],["xyz", 10],["xxz", 12], ["ab", 2]]
## => [["def", 1], ["abc", 2], ["de", 5], ["xyz", 10], ["xxz", 12], ["ab", 2]] 
a.sort
## => [["ab", 2], ["abc", 2], ["de", 5], ["def", 1], ["xxz", 12], ["xyz", 10]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this and both answers under working well, giving rep to all of you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
a.sort_by { |x,y| x }
```